# How to make EF migrations scripts for different databases with same structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with Entity Framework. Initially I used sql server community edition to create tables for models. Now I changed the DB to Mysql and tried to apply the migrations on the DB. For some, it worked and for some, it didn't (specifically when it has dbo. prefix before table names).

Q: I wanted to know if there is a way to maintain different migration scripts for the different types of databases and based on the clients budget generate sql scripts accordingly.(Say my client can afford MySql for now and later SqlServer). My Specific goal is to generate scripts for all the listed DBs say I have different providers like POSTGRESQL, RAVENDB, MYSQL, SQLSERVER etc.

I do know that I can create ANSI standard scripts later from one DB and copy to other DBs but I need EF versioning for each type, for now that is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change the Configuration on the fly in `OnModelCreating` and then keep the different migrations in separate assemblies if needed?

`// OnModelCreating
builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomConfiguration());`

Honestly I'd rather not go this path and make sure you create (and test!) reusable (ANSI) migrations.

Comment: Thanks but I don't find the OnModelCreating or ApplyConfiguration anywhere in my code. I have searched the entire code. 
I am developing MVC 5 application but I am completely new to it.

Comment: Is is an overwritable method in DbContext. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.